# How can I set a custom time for "remember me" in laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I use `Auth::login($user, true);` to remember a user's login status. But it remembers for about 5 years. That is too long. How can I customize the "remember me" cookie time?

Answer (score 2):

By taking a look at Laravel's [source code](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Auth.Guard.html), I don't think that's possible. If you really need this behavior, you could try to login users without the `remember` flag, and create your own cookies.

This is the `login` function:

```
public function login(UserInterface $user, $remember = false)
{
    ...
    if ($remember)
    {
        $this->queuedCookies[] = $this->createRecaller($id); 
    }
    ...
}
```

And this is `createRecaller`, which is calling the `forever` method.

```
protected function createRecaller($id)
{
    return $this->getCookieJar()->forever($this->getRecallerName(), $id);
}
```

---

However, from user's point of view, I think that checking the `remember me` checkbox in a login form and have to log in again after X period of time, is annoying. I would only do this if it's a mandatory requirement (for example, legal reasons).